# ggplot segments with dash dash/ vertical line

Tags: ggplot2, visualization, geom-segment

I am doing a plot similar to this idea

```
library(ggrepel)
library(ggplot2)

name<-c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","A10","A11","A12","A13","A14","A15","A16","A17","A18")


gr<-factor(c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D","D"))
est<-c(6.5,-5.7,7.1,7.5,7.1,6.6,11.0,10.8,-13.9,-8.1,10.1,8.2,-11.1,-5.7,-7.7,-6.5,-4.8,-5.5)
low<-c(1.5,-10.7,2.4,2.5,1.4,0.9,2,3.6,-22.9,-16,0.1,1,-19.6,-10.1,-14.4,-12.7,-9.3,-10.9)
up<-c(11.6,-0.7,11.8,12.4,12.7,12.3,20.1,18.1,-4.9,-0.1,20.1,15.4,-2.6,-1.3,-1.1,-0.2,-0.3,-0.2)

df1<-data.frame(name,gr,est,low,up)

#Plot 1

p1<-ggplot(df1%>%filter(gr=="A"), aes(x=name, est,color="blue2"))+theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_color_manual(values = colores[c(7,3)])+
  geom_segment(aes(x=name,xend=name,y=up,yend=low),size=1.2)+
  geom_point(aes(x=name,y=est,color="red"))+
  geom_point(aes(x=name,y=low,color="red"))+
  geom_point(aes(x=name,y=up,color="red"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = colores)+
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = est,y = est),
                   box.padding   = 0.35, 
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = 'grey50') +
  
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = low,y = low),
                   box.padding   = 0.35, 
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = 'grey50') +
  
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = up,y = up),label.size = 0.5,
                   box.padding   = 0.25, 
                   point.padding = 0.9,
                   segment.color = 'grey50') +labs(title="Title",
                                                   subtitle=" Subtitle")+coord_flip()
p1
```

I got the next plot:

[image]

However, I would like to change each border of each segment where I have added a red point a line.

something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One quick option would be to add a `geom_errorbar` before the `geom_segment`. One drawback is that the segment will overlap the errorbars. Hence, IMHO the cleanest approach would be use two `geom_segments` to add the "errorbar" like line endings. To this end we have to convert your `name` column to a numeric after (!!) filtering the dataset:

```
df1_filtered <- df1 %>% 
  filter(gr == "A")

df1_filtered$name_num <- as.numeric(factor(df1_filtered$name))
w <- .2

ggplot(df1_filtered, aes(x = name, est)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = name, xend = name, y = up, yend = low), size = 1.2, color = "blue2") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = name_num - w / 2, xend = name_num + w / 2, y = up, yend = up), size = 1.2, color = "red") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = name_num - w / 2, xend = name_num + w / 2, y = low, yend = low), size = 1.2, color = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(y = est), color = "red") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = est, y = est),
    box.padding   = 0.35,
    point.padding = 0.5,
    segment.color = "grey50"
  ) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = low, y = low),
    box.padding   = 0.35,
    point.padding = 0.5,
    segment.color = "grey50"
  ) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = up, y = up),
    label.size = 0.5,
    box.padding = 0.25,
    point.padding = 0.9,
    segment.color = "grey50"
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Title",
    subtitle = " Subtitle"
  ) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

And as a reference here is the code using `geom_errobar`:

```
ggplot(df1 %>% filter(gr == "A"), aes(x = name, est)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = low, ymax = up), color = "red", size = 1.2, width = .2) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = name, xend = name, y = up, yend = low), size = 1.2, color = "blue2") +
  geom_point(aes(y = est), color = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(y = low), shape = 15, color = "red", size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = up), shape = 15, color = "red", size = 1) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = est, y = est),
    box.padding   = 0.35,
    point.padding = 0.5,
    segment.color = "grey50"
  ) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = low, y = low),
    box.padding   = 0.35,
    point.padding = 0.5,
    segment.color = "grey50"
  ) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = up, y = up),
    label.size = 0.5,
    box.padding = 0.25,
    point.padding = 0.9,
    segment.color = "grey50"
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Title",
    subtitle = " Subtitle"
  ) +
  coord_flip()
```